# How to change activity after onclick action with data binding

Tags: java, android, data-binding

i have the edit view and button in main activity. Here is the button code:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            style="@style/buttonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:onClick="@{handler::onButtonClick}"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
```

how can i change activity in onButtonClick method?

Comment: What do you mean by "change activity"?
Move to another activity?

Comment: yeah, change activity

Comment: I added the answer that will help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Here you can edit the view and change activity

            // Change Activity using Intent
            startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Yes, it did, but can I do this not in main acrivity class?

Comment: Yes, you can do it in any activity, just replace "CurrentActivity" with you activity name

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/editText"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText" />
```

And add this function to your java code:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivityClass.class);
     context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your main Activity

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),YOURACTIVITYNAME.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have the following code:
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
but nothing works

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: You should add your main activity so we could see how youre implementing the onButtonClick method